# how to save search parameters for later use in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a search form where User can enter data to be searched and after that he has the possibility to use pagination.

For pagination I have to send again and again the searched paramters. What will be the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send that searched parameter through `url` as named parameter. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/cakeproj/controllers/action/q:searchedItem/...
```

and you'll get this named parameter in controller's action like:

```
$this->params->named;
```

***or***

```
$this->params['named'];
```

and it will give you an array like:

```
[named] => Array
(
    [q] => 'searchedItem',
    ....
)
```

To get the searched item directly:

```
$this->params->named['q'];
```

***or***

```
$this->params['named']['q'];
```